# Refresh Token Rotation - is it really enough?

Tags: security, authentication, openid-connect, access-token, refresh-token

In the context of a Single-Page Application (JavaScript) authenticating with an OIDC Server, the standard and recommended way to keep the session alive (getting more tokens after they expire) is to use a HttpOnly Cookie and perform a Silent Renew within an iframe. Great, no Refresh Tokens involved since the browser cannot keep a secret.

It seems now that the browsers are going to prevent Cross-origin Cookies (Safari and Brave already do, Chrome will be next it seems), so if the Server is on a different domain it appears that the only way in the future will be to use **Refresh Tokens** with **Refresh Token Rotation** (and possibly **Reuse Detection**) which seems to mitigate the problems. But does it really?

***Scenario 1)*** Refresh Token (RT1) is stolen, user requests a new token and gets back a new Refresh Token too (RT2) because of rotation. RT1 is now invalid and cannot be used by the attacker. Great.

***Scenario 2)*** Refresh Token (RT1) is stolen, the attacker performs a request to get a new token (RT2), user uses the old token (RT1) and now everything is discarded and the user has to login again (Reuse Detection) and the attacker's token is invalid too. Great. Well I kinda see a problem here (the user has to login again and doesn't know why) but at least the problem is solved.

***Scenario 3)*** This is the scenario I don't see mentioned anywhere. Suppose the attacker is stealing every subsequent RT without using them, so it proceeds to steal RT1. User refreshes, and attacker steals RT2 too. Everything is working fine because the attacker hasn't used the token, but maybe he sent all tokens somewhere else to be stored. At the end, the user closes the window and the attacker has extracted both RT1, and RT2. At this point, the attacker can use the latest RT (RT2) to impersonate the user until the user comes back to the app. Say he stays away for a week, the attacker has new Access Tokens for a week (he can continuously refresh the tokens). Nobody notices anything until the end. With a Cookie, the attacker could operate only during the browser session, now it has much more time for that.

So... is RTR with Reuse Detection really secure enough? The main argument is "it's always a risk/benefit choice", I get it, but how can it be 2020 and we're still having troubles with browsers? Do you see anything wrong with the 3rd Scenario that I'm missing? Honestly, session cookies has always been the best choice, the fact that browsers are going to prevent us from using them for this common scenario drives me nuts :)

Thanks.

PS. I'll copy here some resources I find about this problem:

- https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/refresh-token-protection-implications.html

"*RTR is not a catch-all security measure. If an attacker manages to obtain the last refresh token before the app closes, they might be able to keep rotating the stolen refresh token. To avoid long-term abuse of a stolen refresh token, the security token service can link the lifetime of that refresh token to the lifetime of the user’s session with the security token service. Doing so would invalidate the refresh token when the session expires.*"

This is the point I made in scenario 3, but the solution he suggests is to link the RT to the user's session. So, we're using Session Cookies again, aren't we? What if we cannot use them? RTs in this scenario should be an alternative for when we cannot use cross-domain cookies.

- https://leastprivilege.com/2020/03/31/spas-are-dead/

This one seems to agree with me on that RTs even with RTR are not secure enough and the SPA would need to be connected to a backend on the same domain in order to work as before.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting area this, and it is often a trade off between Usability, Security, Performance and Cost. The current state of the industry is pretty unsatisfactory, but I hope some of this helps you to understand the main issues.

**REFRESH TOKENS IN THE BROWSER**

Before using this solution I would ensure that the Authorization Server properly supported the [OAuth 2.1 RTP recommendations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-parecki-oauth-v2-1-03#section-6.1) - not many Authorization Servers do.

I would then ensure that I only stored refresh tokens in the app's memory, since it is not recommended to store tokens in local storage. This then means that:

- Multi tab browsing or reloading a page will require a token refresh via the older iframe based solution you mention
- This will not work silently in Safari so there will be a browser redirect which usability stakeholders are likely to complain about

**SECURITY ASPECTS**

Your SPA security is about more than just token mechanics of course. You need to ensure that security stakeholders accept the solution, and you need to think about threats such as what an attacker can do with a token / cookie.

**BACK END FOR FRONT END PATTERN**

One of the big problems with this is that you typically need a back end that issues same domain HTTP only encrypted cookies, coded in C#, Node, Java etc.

This can be very intrusive for an SPA architecture:

- Pushing web static content to many global locations via a Content Delivery Network is either not possible or more difficult
- You may require double hops on every API call from the SPA, which adds complexity, especially around areas such as caching and API error responses
- Security is not 'solved' by using auth cookies, and many browser threats still need to be dealt with

**2022 UPDATE**

These days I would recommend keeping tokens out of the browser, since this is now perceived poorly. Maybe have a look at the [Token Handler Pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-overview/) as a modern solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read the resources asap :) But ultimately you're saying what I'm saying: even with RTR and Reuse Detection, this doesn't cover the 3rd scenario if you don't use ALSO cookies. Remember that whoever recommends this path is doing it to avoid Cookies, so I agree with you on that "RTs should not be stored" (even if they can be stolen from memory too...) but that defeats their purpose (an alternative to Silent Renew). If the user has to login again after a refresh, what's the benefit then? Your final solutions seems right to me: you're using a Cookie to maintain the session, not RTs :)

Comment: Yes - think we agree - though I would say it's about usability and simplicity as well as security. If I could use refresh tokens with the recommended RTP, store them only in memory, and there were no usability problems, I would go for that option. I would argue that the RT is no worse than how a user can easily access their own auth cookie with a proxy tool such as Fiddler. Of course my Web UI would also need good XSS and Content Security Policy protection so that malicious Javascript code cannot access the RT, in the same way as it cannot access an auth cookie.

Comment: Yes, but malicious code could never access an auth cookie if done correctly :) The only problem would be CSRF but we have tools for that. If you got an XSS issue (and you're pretty much screwed anyway) with a proper Cookie the attacker can only work until the victim's browser is closed, however if he steals a RT he can create infinite ATs, for that matter I consider it worse. The only way to access a Cookie would be, as you said, using external tools: we have no control over that. If someone gets into your user's device, that's not the developer's responsibility I think.

Comment: Also, we're not even talking about handling those tokens: Rotation, Reuse Detection, Revocation, more bandwidth needed, etc... It's doable, the point is it doesn't come for free, and you always have to maintain some sort of state on the server too.